# Programmatically activate a specific Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

If I have multiple Arduinos plugged into the same computer, is there a way that I can control them both with the same script while also being able to select which one I want to control programmatically?

For instance, the pseudo code may look something like:

stop controlling Arduino2; // Make sure Arduino 2 is not listening

start controlling Arduino1; //Make sure Arduino 1 is listening

set pin 10 high; //Set pin 10 on Arduino 1 to high

stop controlling Arduino1; // Make sure Arduino 1 is not listening

start controlling Arduino2; // Make sure Arduino 2 is listening

set pin 10 high; // Set pin 10 on Arduino 2 high

Windows OS
Currently using Arduino built in language, open to using anything though.

Comment: What OS are you on? What scripting language are you using?

Comment: Each Arduino will appear as a distinct serial device to programs on the host.  It would be easiest to have something which "finds" all of them, and then keeps track of which is which so that it can talk to the desired one.  Giving each a unique response to a "who are you?" query would help.